# Find the number of elements of the cyclic subgroup $\left\langle -\frac{1}{ 2}+\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} i \right\rangle$ of $\mathbb{C}^*$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the number of elements of the cyclic subgroup $\left\langle -\frac{1}{ 2}+\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} i \right\rangle$ of $\mathbb{C}^*$.

**Answer:**

Since $\left\langle -\frac{1}{ 2}+\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} i \right\rangle=-\cos (2 \pi/6)+i \sin (2 \pi/6)$ is a generator of $U_6$ and $U_6$ has order $\phi(6)=2$, the cyclic subgroup generated by $\left\langle -\frac{1}{ 2}+\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} i \right\rangle$ has $2$ elements.

Am I right ?

I think $\cos (2 \pi/n)+i \sin (2 \pi/n)$ has order $\phi(n)$ but in the above case it is like the form $-\cos (2 \pi/n)+i \sin (2 \pi/n)$. This confuses me

Comment: Are you sure that $\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})=-\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Well, the sine part is also wrong.

Comment: @carmichael561, actually the previous one was correct but I mistakenly put the angle.

Comment: I think $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ is what you're looking for. And you can easily find the order of the group by finding the order of the given element. I would write it as $\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{3})$ though.

Comment: @carmichael561, so it is a order $2$ element and hence order $2$ cyclic subgroup.

Comment: Try computing the powers of $\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{3})$ and see when you get $1$. The order is not $2$.

Comment: Please explain why you think the element has order 2. There seems to be a big misunderstanding here.

Comment: @actually I am thinking the order should be $\phi(n)=\phi(denominator)$ but which is not correct though

Comment: @carmichael561, computing powers $(exp(2 \pi i/3))^3=exp(2 \pi i)=identity$ and so oder $3$

Comment: Yes, the generator is a complex cube root of $1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$\cos \left ( \dfrac{2\pi}{3} \right ) = -\dfrac{1}{2}, \tag 1$

and

$\sin \left ( \dfrac{2\pi}{3} \right ) = \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2}; \tag 2$

thus,

$-\dfrac{1}{2} + i \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2} = \cos \left ( \dfrac{2\pi}{3} \right )  + i \sin \left ( \dfrac{2\pi}{3} \right ) = e^{2 \pi i /3}; \tag 3$

it follows that, for any $m \in \Bbb Z$,

$\left (-\dfrac{1}{2} + i \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2} \right )^m = e^{2 m \pi i/3}; \tag 4$

in particular we have

$\left (-\dfrac{1}{2} + i \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2} \right )^2 = e^{4\pi i/3}, \tag 5$

$\left (-\dfrac{1}{2} + i \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2} \right )^3 = e^{6 \pi i/3} = e^{2\pi i} = 1; \tag 6$

at this point the powers if $e^{2\pi i/3}$ commence to cycle around so that

$\left (-\dfrac{1}{2} + i \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2} \right )^4 = e^{8 \pi i/3} = e^{6\pi i / 3} e^{2 \pi i / 3}= e^{2 \pi i} e^{2 \pi i / 3}= e^{2 \pi i / 3}, \tag 7$

$\left (-\dfrac{1}{2} + i \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2} \right )^5 = e^{10 \pi i/3} = e^{6\pi i / 3} e^{4 \pi i / 3}= e^{2 \pi i} e^{4 \pi i / 3}= e^{4 \pi i / 3}, \tag 8$

$\left (-\dfrac{1}{2} + i \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2} \right )^6 = e^{12 \pi i/3} = e^{4 \pi i}= (e^{2 \pi i})^2 = 1^2 = 1, \tag 9$

and so forth.  Indeed, since the division algorithm yields

$m = 3k + j, \; j = 0, 1, 2,  \tag{10}$

(4) may be written

$\left (-\dfrac{1}{2} + i \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2} \right )^m = e^{2 m \pi i/3} = e^{2 (3k + j) \pi i/3} = e^{6k\pi i / 3 + 2j \pi i / 3}$
$= e^{6k \pi i / 3}e^{2j\pi i / 3} = (e^{2\pi i})^k e^{2j \pi i /3} = e^{2j \pi i /3}, 0 \le j \le 2; \tag{11}$

which shows that every power of $e^{2 \pi i/ 3}$ lies in the set

$\{1, e^{2 \pi i / 3}, e^{4 \pi i / 3 } \}, \tag {12}$

which clearly is possessed of a group structure in light of the preceding calculations.  Since there exists precisely one group of order $3$,

$\Bbb Z_3 = \{0, 1, 2 \} \tag{13},$

and it is isomorphic to (12) *via* the map taking

$0 \mapsto 1, \; 1 \mapsto e^{2 \pi i / 3}, \; 2 \mapsto e^{4 \pi i / 3}, \tag{14}$

we conclude that the subgroup of $\Bbb C^\ast$ generated by $e^{2\pi i / 3}$ has exactly $3$ elements.

Answer (score 1):

That is $\langle e^{\frac{2\pi i}3}\rangle $.  $\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}3}$ is a primitive $3$rd root of unity,  and has order $3$.  Thus we get the cyclic group of order $3$.

Another description would be as the $3$-torsion subgroup of the circle group.

$\phi (n)$ is the number of *primitive* $n$-th roots of unity.  Primitive roots generate the whole group $C_n$.

But an arbitrary element of $C_n$ is just an $n$-th root of unity (at least,  as one way of looking at it).   There are of course $n$ of them.